# "Am Marktplatz" or "auf dem Marktplatz"?

Tags: preposition

My textbook says that usually "an" is used for "at," e.g., "am Bahnhof," "an der "Haltestelle,"
but there are certain nouns that take "auf" to mean the same thing, e.g., 'auf der Fussballplatz," :auf der Post," "auf dem Markt." But later it gives these sentences: "Er is am Marktplatz," and "am Postamt." Please explain.

Comment: @infinitezero: The question you linked to seems to be exclusively about *Weg* while this one is more general. Since the choice of location preposition can depend on the location in question, I think a more general answer is called for.

Comment: I later saw, there is the same question about Platz as well.